# The altruists GTA V browser website

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

What is the meaning of this website

and what does it say?

It is in game and in the browser

[image: Here]

Comment: Unless this website is referenced in-game somewhere, this is off-topic.  If it is, I'd encourage you to add where that is.

Comment: Its in the game please only comment if you know what you are talking about, this is in game on the GTA browser

Comment: @Frank the Altruists are a cult in the game, so it's on-topic

Comment: Is this GTA Online, or GTA 5? It looks like it's Morse code.

Comment: I pruned a lot of unnecessary comments on this post. Let's not speculate on anyone's intent, and keep things civil.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an in-game website for the Altruist Cult.  The Altruist Cult is a malevolent religion comprised entirely of old men from the baby boom generation that follow Altruism and believe that all other generations after them are the cause of all problems in the world. They also have distaste for technology, even though some members use cars, and the entire group maintains a website.

Members can be seen walking around half naked, some fully naked. The cult makes their home in a small, but functional fortified village in the Chiliad Mountain State Wilderness, with numerous buildings painted with their livery.  [More info here](http://gta.wikia.com/Altruist_Cult)

It's written in morse code and translates as the following:

> The industrial revolution has been a disaster to the stability of the
>   human race.
>
> Almost all would agree that continued focus on the superiority of the
>   sub 40 younger generation will result in the catastrophic and tragic
>   end to our civilization.
>
> Man is a nocturnal animal by nature.
>
> Those who exist in the industrial-technological society, suffer from
>   psychological problems.
>
> Hypervitaminosis D causes abnormally high concentrations of calcium,
>   which can cause harm to the heart, kidneys and bones. Toxic
>   concentrations are a direct result of exposure to the sun.
>
> Crowding causes stress and aggression
>
> Primitive societies, ones where clothes and tools of the industrial
>   revolution were not needed, provided a stable framework for the
>   function of society
>
> One can not complain about the decay traditional values yet embrace
>   technology
>
> A man as an individual, working with an autonomous group of
>   individuals, all of whom are naked in spirit and in the cloth, remain
>   healthy to himself and others.
>
> Sub 40s only exist as subsistence to the altruistic man and gains life
>   from consuming them
>
> Ban clothes. Ban lies. Ban youth. Ban deceit. Eat of the flesh. Drink
>   of the blood. We know. Altruism. The greatest good, for the greatest
>   generation. We shall boom again.

Take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWn7wf7ODhU) which explains all of it as well.

Comment: IS ALL CAPS REALLY NECESSARY?

Comment: @tzhx It was on the website that I copied it from, so yes they are as I couldn't be bothered to de-caps it